# How to compile SCSS with always importing a certain file

Tags: ruby, import, sass

I compile my SCSS files into CSS strings from a Ruby script using code as follows:

```
render = Sass::Engine.new(File.read(scss), options).render
```

where `scss` and `options` are the SCSS file and the options.

I want to import a fixed file (let's say whose path is `/path/to/foo`) every time I compile my SCSS file. This can be done by writing

```
@import "/path/to/foo";
```

at the beginning of every file. But I want to omit that and let it be imported automatically. I believe it should be possible by overriding some part of the sass gem so that whenever I do `Sass::Engine.new` or `render`, it should always start as if `@import "/path/to/foo";` was read.

A naive way might be doing something like:

```
render = Sass::Engine.new("@import \"/path/to/foo\";\n" + File.read(scss), options)
.render
```

but that messes up the line number in error messages, and it also looks like a dirty hack.

How can I minimally override parts of the sass gem so that compilation always starts with importing the `"/path/to/foo"` file even if `@import "/path/to/foo";` is not written in the SCSS file?